# Converting to using URL router is causing a ImproperlyConfigured exception

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

I have been working through the Django Rest Framework tutorial and on the [very last step](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/#using-routers) I am encountering the error:

> Exception Type:   ImproperlyConfigured.
> Exception Value:
> Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "snippet-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the lookup_field attribute on this field.

When trying to view either /settings/ or /users/ (visiting any user pages yields the same exception but with "user-detail" in place of "snippet-detail") as well as any specific indices of them, etc. All that works is root and login.

All my code thus far has been working fine and I'm very confused as to why copy-pasting from the tutorial would yield such catastrophic results

In comparing my snippets files with those available on the [tutorial's repo](https://github.com/encode/rest-framework-tutorial)  I have not been able to find any significant difference (all that I've found is inconsistencies in whitespace). That being said, here is the code I'm using.

snippets/views.py:

```
from snippets.models import Snippet
from snippets.serializers import SnippetSerializer, UserSerializer
from rest_framework import generics, permissions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from snippets.permissions import IsOwnerOrReadOnly
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions


from rest_framework import viewsets

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list` and `retrieve` actions.
    """
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class SnippetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    This viewset automatically provides `list`, `create`, `retrieve`,
    `update` and `destroy` actions.

    Additionally we also provide an extra `highlight` action.
    """
    queryset = Snippet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SnippetSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,
                          IsOwnerOrReadOnly]

    @action(detail=True, renderer_classes=[renderers.StaticHTMLRenderer])
    def highlight(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        snippet = self.get_object()
        return Response(snippet.highlighted)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
```

snippets/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from snippets import views

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet,basename="snippets")
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet,basename="users")

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

snippets/serializers.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework import serializers

from snippets.models import Snippet


class SnippetSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='owner.username')
    highlight = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(
        view_name='snippet-highlight', format='html')

    class Meta:
        model = Snippet
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'highlight', 'owner', 'title', 'code',
                  'linenos', 'language', 'style')


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    snippets = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        many=True, view_name='snippet-detail', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'username', 'snippets')
```

tutorial/urls.py:

```
"""tutorial URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('snippets.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += [
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
]
```

Comment: You passed `basename` for both viewsets in your router, the basename will be used to generate the view names: `snippets-detail` and `users-detail`

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks so much! Was getting really frustrated. To clarify for anyone initially confused as I was, the issue was the base names based being pluralized (creating routes users-details and snippets-detail rather than user-detail and snippet-detail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router was being passed the wrong base names (plural forms of snippet and user rather than singular). Thanks to @IainShelvington for the answer in the comments!
To elaborate:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from snippets import views

    # Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
    router = DefaultRouter()
    router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet,basename="snippets")
    router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet,basename="users")
    
    # The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', include(router.urls)),
    ]
```

should have been

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from snippets import views

# Create a router and register our viewsets with it.
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'snippets', views.SnippetViewSet,basename="snippet")
router.register(r'users', views.UserViewSet,basename="user")

# The API URLs are now determined automatically by the router.
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: They should fix it in their tutorial docs